# Javascript regular expression not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

This regular expression fails in Firefox but works in IE.

```
function validate(x) {
   return /.(jpeg|jpg)$/ig.test(x);
}
```

Can anybody explain why?

Comment: Please update with a *valid* test-case (one that shows "failing" inputs). Thanks.

Comment: can you explain how this code works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are testing with just the filename, then setting the 'g' flag for global doesn't make much sense since you are matching at the end of the string anyway - i ran the following:

```
function validate(x) {
  return /\.(jpeg|jpg)$/i.test(x);
}

var imagename = 'blah.jpg';
alert (validate(imagename));    // should be true
imagename = 'blah.jpeg';
alert (validate(imagename));    // should be true
imagename = 'blah.png';
alert (validate(imagename));    // should be false
```

all three tests came out as expected in FF.

As for 'how it works' - regular expressions can get quite tricky - but I will explain the details of the above pattern:

- the slash **/** is used to delimit the pattern
- the dot **.** has a special meaning of 'any non-whitespace character' - writing it as **\.** forces the patten to only match a fullstop
- the **()** mean a collection (it gets more complicated, but that covers this usage)
- the **|** means 'or'
- **$** means the end of the string (or the end of a line in a multi-line text)
- the **i** after the second slash means 'case insensitive'
- the **g** means 'global' - which doesn't make much sense in this case, so I removed it.

so..

```
/\.(jpeg|jpg)$/i
```

means "a string ending in either .jpeg or .jpg - ignoring case"

so... .JPEG, .jpg, .JpeG, etc... will all pass now...

Comment: Or, reading straight from the RE, it matches a string "with a dot followed by either 'jpeg' or 'jpg', all at the end and ignoring case"

Comment: thanks a lot man I just removed the g and add the forward slash infront of "."..it works great man cool

Comment: The `g` means "global", not "greedy" according to the ECMAScript Language Specification section 15.10.4.1. However, it *is* probably not needed here, so removing it would be a good plan.

Comment: I think they mean the same thing though, don't they? I came into RegEx from PHP and Perl, so I tend to default to their terms...

Comment: ack - morning coffee has kicked in and I realised I was thinking fuzzily... global and greedy are not the same thing at all...

 - global = all matches in a string
 - greedy = match as much as possible in a single pattern

Answer (score 3):

In regex expressions, "." by itself means "any character".  Did you mean "\." to mean "period"?

Answer (score 2):

The function is using a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) pattern `.(jpeg|jpg)$` to test strings.  It looks like the intent is to validate filenames to make sure they have an extension of either `jpg` or `jpeg`.

As James Bailey pointed out, there is an error in that the period should be escaped with a backslash.  A period in a regular expression will match any character.  So, as shown, the pattern would match both `imagexjpg` and `image.jpg`.